# How to access inbox messages in Windows Phone 7.5/7.8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am making an application which basically tells how many messages you received by a specific user. The only problem is that I don't know how to access inbox messages.

Is there any way to do that? I want all my messages in a list or something which I can use in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access mail messages nor SMS messages in Windows Phone normally. Unfortunately, it is not allowed and I don't think you will see it soon. You can, however, try to write your own mail client instead which would offer the desired functionality.

Comment: there are some apps but for that you need to root your phone. I am not sure I can do that same without rooting the phone.

Comment: I know you could do it then, but you cannot distribute such application via Marketplace. Plus, only enthusiasts could use it, not sure if they would.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to count the messages in WP7 & WP8 . You can only send SMS from "SmsComposeTask" class and it will show into your sms list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access in any WP platform, yet. You can only send SMS via [SMSComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.smscomposetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class (Launcher). Or, you can vote for this new functionality [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1901813-sms-access-api).

Hope you find useful.

Regards.